# Video card set up

Tags: graphics-card

I have a EVGA Ge-force 750ti 2GB graphic card. I install it on  ASRock Z77 Extreme4 LGA 1155 Intel Z77 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard with a Intel® Core™ i7-3770 K Processor

I install the card and the system does not see it. It is install in the PCIe 3.0 x16 slot. I removed the Intel HD Graphics drivers. Same, thing it is not detected. I am running Win 7 Ultimate 64.

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Ensure you've inserted it correctly (re-seat it), and are supplying any auxiliary power it may need.  Beyond that, the video card may simply be defective -- try it in another computer.

Comment: was the slot open / unused for sometime. Try cleaning the slot and retry. Sometimes dust accumulation inside the slot may prevent proper contacts.

Comment: Did you check BIOS to see if their is an option to set graphics card being PCIe rather than onboard.

Answer (score 0):

do the following:

1.make sure the graphics card is properly inserted.

2.make sure the cable from the power supply is properly inserted.

3.make sure the cable connecting the monitor and graphics card  is not faulty.

4.try reseting  your bios to deafults.

only do step 5 if nothing works

5.try updating your bios.this will solve problem the problem with bios,if you have any.

note:updating your bios should be done very carefully.if you are not sure how to update bios,don't do it yourself.try contacting someone who knows that.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SuperUser! We strongly recommend giving a substantial amount of  detail... Also, are you sure? this doesn't seem to answer the question...

Comment: i edited it ,not community.sorry for the vague answer